# Xamarin android with SignalR returns 400 status code when connecting

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, signalr

I have `Xamarin` project for android and `Asp.Net Web Api` project. I want to use `SignalR`, but when I try connect from android ir return 400 status.

`SignalR` configuaration is minimal and breakpoint being hit in `Configuration` method.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Hub class

```
public class MainHub: Hub
{
    public void Send(string platform, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.messageReceived(platform, message);
    }
}
```

In android project I create `HubConnection` using `10.0.2.2` and web api port `65443`.

```
public class ServerCommunicationService
{
    private readonly string _platform;
    public readonly HubConnection _connection;
    private readonly IHubProxy _proxy;

    public event EventHandler<string> OnMessageReceived;

    public ServerCommunicationService(string platform)
    {
        _platform = platform;
        _connection = new HubConnection("http://10.0.2.2:65443");
        _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("MainHub");
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        await _connection.Start();

        _proxy.On("messageReceived", (string platform, string message) =>
        {
            if (OnMessageReceived != null)
                OnMessageReceived(this, string.Format("{0}: {1}", platform, message));
        });
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return _proxy.Invoke("Send", _platform, message);
    }
}
```

However I get error

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>       {
>           Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>           Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 07:59:01 GMT
>           Connection: close
>           Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>           Content-Length: 334
>       }

What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: Try http://10.0.2.2:65443/signalr/negotiate. If you still receive 400 troubleshoot on the server.

Comment: @Pawel I still get 400 status. Using your url I get url like that `http://10.0.2.2:65443/signalr/negotiate/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=........`. When I published web api on a server, it is working properly. Mayby I need to open some ports or redirect something?

Comment: I would think that 400 is sent by the server so the ports should be open.

Comment: I added inbound rule for this 65443 port on my computer's firewall. Did not change anything....

Comment: Any developments on this question?